# Can I use a view helper in my request spec, or am I Doing It Wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm going through a Rails app and updating all the flash messages to use our localization file. We have some request specs like this:

```
it "should alert on failure" do
  put "/lolcats/#{@lolcat.id}", lolcat: {caption: nil}
  response.body.should have_selector(
    "#flash-alert", text: "There was an error saving, please see below."
  )
end
```

I thought I'd rewrite that to expect whatever text is in the i18n file:

```
response.body.should have_selector(
  "#flash-alert", text: helper.t('flash.save_failed')
)
```

However, neither `t` nor `helper.t` are available here. I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `helper' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup...>
```

**Can I access this view helper somehow, or am I Doing It Wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `t` in Rails views is a shortcut for `I18n.t` you can use latter in your spec.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? :)